# Container div over its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this HTML. Flash# divs are for flash objects (swfobjects). There is a container div `container2` which I want to place it over its content, like a curtain when flash objects are updated and rebuilt to prevent the user from clicking them.

```
//rest of html code
<div id="container2">
<div id="flash1"></div>
<div id="flash2"></div>
<div id="flash3"></div>
<div id="flash4"></div>
</div>
//rest of html code
```

I've tried an absolute positioned div over the flash divs to achieve this but this doesn't work with jQuery `slidetoggle` effect which I use in a previous div (it has a weird width behaviour that narrows the page) therefore I've decided to try this different approach, which also seems to be more efficient.
Any idea of how to achieve this? I'm open mainly to jQuery but also to strict Javascript or whatever.

Comment: did you try to add z-index for all divs? this should do the trick. position: absolute for conteiner2 (btw: avoid such name!) and z-index:100, and for all other position: relative and z-index: 10 (z-index works only if position is set). if your only issue is width, did you try to set it manually? with which browser do you have issue with slidetoggle? if it is in IE, then it is well known issue, that you should not have position: absolute, in all order browsers it works. However there are some fixes to that, for example, they advice setting height 101% or zoom: 1.

Comment: I've already added a z-index to both flash divs and container2 (the name is only for make the question more clear) in the css file to -1 for the first and 1 for the latter. I just fadeIn and fadeOut using jquery functions

Comment: ok, you did not answer to the question whether you have this issue only in internet explorer. I had recently the same problem with slidetoggle, only in this browser. I had suggested several workarounds , not sure if you tried them. Here is a post (with useful comments) about [slidetoggle in internet explorer](http://www.ndoherty.biz/2007/09/jquery-slidetoggle-and-internet-explorer/). You can always try to set position absolute to flash1, flash2, flash3 etc and remove it from container2... it will be a little more work but should do the trick.

Comment: I cannot check if this issue appears in other browser apart from IE8. I assume this is another weird IE behaviour because following the method of the link it seems to work. This is to completely remove all css rules applied for the slid div which is acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually follow the workaround proposed by mkk. This is to completely delete any applied rule to the slid div and have just worked for me.
Simple but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Delete div when slide up.
Add div when slide down.

Good luck =)

Answer (score 0):

For me you have to add another div inside the container and use it to overlay the flash objs. Leave the container in position:relative and overflow:hidden and use a div child to cover the content!

Marco

Comment: If I do this I have to set a height and width value to that div and this causes the page to narrow when a slide up a previous div.

Comment: Now i'm away from my mac. If you can wait this evening i will try out! Bye

Comment: Well, I'm stucked with this since monday, a day more won't hurt much more

Comment: I've achieved that using a 'curtain' div which I position absolutely. The problem is when I slide down & slide up other previous div seems like all elements with defined width get narrowed. So I can either fix the narrowing issue or try to make the container div like the curtain